# Fancybox Gallery showing all images

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, fancybox

I currently am using the fancybox-rails gem in order to show a gallery of images.  What I would like to do it to have a single link open up the gallery of all the images.  Here is my current code:

```
 <% for painting in @gallery %>
    <%= link_to "view gallery", painting.image_url.to_s, { :class => "grouped_elements", :rel => "studio_images", :title => painting.caption } %>
 <% end %><br>
```

This code is giving me eight different links, all linking to the same gallery.  I would like just one link to be shown and have that link open the entire gallery.  I understand here that I am creating eight different links, but I want to be able to add to this gallery dynamically when I add a new image.  Below is my JS code:

```
jQuery ->
  $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox({
      'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
      'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
      'speedIn'       :   600,
      'speedOut'      :   200,
      'overlayShow'   :   false
  });<br>
```

Is there something I can do in jQuery that would allow these links to be hidden and just have a single link open the gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place all your links under a hidden division like (rendered html)

```
<div style="display: none"> 
    <a rel="studio_images" class="grouped_elements" href="image01.jpg"></a>
    <a rel="studio_images" class="grouped_elements" href="image02.jpg"></a>
    <a rel="studio_images" class="grouped_elements" href="image03.jpg"></a>
    ... etc.
</div>
```

**Notice** that since the links will be hidden, you don't need to set any thumbnail or text.

You can keep your current fancybox initialization script.

Then, create the single link (outside the hidden `div`) that you will use to fire your gallery, something like this :

```
<a id="triggerGallery" href="image01.jpg">open gallery</a>
```

**Notice** that the `href` points to the first image of the gallery. If javascript is disable, it still will link to this image. Or you could just do `href="javascript:;"`

Then bind a `click` action to the `#triggerGallery` selector like

```
$("#triggerGallery").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".grouped_elements").eq(0).trigger("click");
});
```

You have to write it in the proper rails format though.

**Notice** that we are using `.eq(0)` to target the first element of the gallery.

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c3HLS/)</kbd>